# Is it possible to have a low starting-point game in Wargame: Red Dragon?

Tags: wargame-red-dragon

I'm setting up to try a special ops 1v1 with a friend of mine, and we wanted to know if there was setup with fewer starting points than a 1000 pt Destruction match (with Very Low income rate).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was added after you asked your question or if it's been there all along, but currently 500 points is the lowest possible starting value.

[image]

Comment: Are there certain settings/modes/maps that you have to be using to get that? I never see less than 1000.

Comment: @rsegal if you're playing on a 2v2 map the minimum is 1000 (split between all players on a team). AFAIK you can't play 1v1 on a 2v2 map with less than 1k per player.